# AndEngine - prevent car collision, foresee collision

Tags: box2d, collision-detection, andengine, collision

- Im building a car-traffic game, where the player will drive car
  avoiding collision the bot car should not collide with each other.
- i have a update handler for each car that drives the car at varying
  speeds, but i cant think of a code that could predict a future
  collision with fellow bot car without actual collsion..
- what my code should do is check for collision with the car before the
  current car so that it could change lanes to prevent collision
  any ideas im new to andengine

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sensor body going in front of the actual car and check for its collisions, then when a collision of the sensor body occurs, the car would prevent a collision. Of course you would have to reset the sensor afterwards and I am sure there must be a more elegant solution. Therefore, I will flag this question to be moved to Game development branch of Stack Exchange, people there are be more experienced with these kind of problems.

Comment: thanks yo.. but its hard to find any specific tutorial for my issue

Answer (score 1):

This is an AI problem, you don't actually need to predict the collisions. You just need a set of rules that cars follow which makes them avoid collisions. Try to figure out exactly how *you* avoid collisions in traffic. Then apply these rules to your car. It's easier said than done though.

For example, if I'm going faster than the car in front of me and getting too close I should change lanes or slow down. To program this, you could check the distance between 2 cars, figure out if the one behind is moving faster than the one in front. If so, reduce it's speed or try to change lanes.

Don't go trying to predict if collisions will happen. This is hard, and it's even harder to figure out the proper reaction.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use a ray cast (or a few raycasts) to detect if there is anything within a given range of the car in a certain direction.

Comment: Thanks yo but im new to this ray casts any tutorial or code would be helpful